# Which Linux capability do I need in order to write to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches?

Tags: proc, privileges, docker, capabilities

I am trying to clear my filesystem cache from inside a docker container, like so:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:vivid sh -c "/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

If I run this command I get

```
sh: 1: cannot create /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Read-only file system
```

which is expected, as I cannot write to `/proc` from inside the container.

Now when I call

```
docker run --rm --privileged ubuntu:vivid sh -c "/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

it works, which also makes sense to me, as the `--privileged` container can do (almost) anything on the host.

My question is: how do I find out, which Linux capability I need to set in the command

```
docker run --rm --cap-add=??? ubuntu:vivid sh -c "/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

in order to make this work without having to set `--privileged`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `proc` filesystem doesn't support capabilities, ACL, or even changing basic permissions with `chmod`. Unix permissions determine whether the calling process gets access. Thus only root can write that file. With user namespaces, that's the global root (the one in the original namespace); root in a container doesn't get to change sysctl settings.

As far as I know, the only solution to change a sysctl setting from inside a non-privileged namespace is to arrange a communication channel with the outside (e.g. a socket or pipe), and have the listening process run as root outside the container.

Comment: I put in another answer that solves my problem. Your reply however is absolutely correct for what I asked, so I'll make it the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to the accpted answer by Gilles:
I managed to achieve my goal of writing to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` (or to `/proc` in general, to be precise) in a much easier way when working with docker:

```
docker run -ti --rm -v /proc:/writable_proc ubuntu:vivid bash
# echo 3 > /writable_proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

That does it for my purpose.

Thank you very much for your helpful answer!

Comment: It seems they conflict? It suggests Gile's answer doesn't apply, i.e. docker isn't using user namespaces here.  The extra bind mount should still be subject to the problem Giles mentioned, if Docker was using user namespaces.  Docker doesn't add any user translation layer for mounts which you bind into the container.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following:

```
docker run -ti --rm -v /proc:/writable_proc rhel bash
echo 3 > /writable_proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And, it failed:

```
bash: /writable_proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

I run it with privileged:

```
docker run -ti --rm --privileged -v /proc:/writable_proc rhel bash
echo 3 > /writable_proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And, everything worked, so I am pretty sure that somehow things worked for Gilles because his daemon or cli is configured to use privileged without knowing it:

Comment: I guess it might be because you have SELinux (or AppArmor?) in your docker install.